# Make a subset of a dataframe based on different rows with different strings

Tags: r, subset

This is what my data looks like:

```
structure(list(STATE = c("AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AR", "AR", 
"AR", "AR", "AZ", "AZ", "AZ", "AZ", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CO", 
"CO", "CO", "CO", "CT", "CT", "CT", "CT", "DC", "DC", "DC", "DC", 
"DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "FL", "FL", "FL", "FL", "GA", "GA", "GA", 
"GA", "IA", "IA", "IA", "IA", "ID", "ID", "ID", "ID", "IL", "IL", 
"IL", "IL", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KY", 
"KY", "KY", "KY", "LA", "LA", "LA", "LA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", 
"MD", "MD", "MD", "MD", "ME", "ME", "ME", "ME", "MI", "MI", "MI", 
"MI", "MN", "MN", "MN", "MN", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MS", "MS", 
"MS", "MS", "MT", "MT", "MT", "MT", "NC", "NC", "NC", "NC", "ND", 
"ND", "ND", "ND", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NH", "NH", "NH", "NH", 
"NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NM", "NM", "NM", "NM", "NV", "NV", "NV", 
"NV", "NY", "NY", "NY", "NY", "OH", "OH", "OH", "OH", "OK", "OK", 
"OK", "OK", "OR", "OR", "OR", "OR", "PA", "PA", "PA", "PA", "RI", 
"RI", "RI", "RI", "SC", "SC", "SC", "SC", "SD", "SD", "SD", "SD", 
"TN", "TN", "TN", "TN", "TX", "TX", "TX", "TX", "UT", "UT", "UT", 
"UT", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VT", "VT", "VT", "VT", "WA", "WA", 
"WA", "WA", "WI", "WI", "WI", "WI", "WV", "WV", "WV", "WV", "WY", 
"WY", "WY", "WY"), STATEFP = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 11, 11, 11, 11, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 19, 19, 19, 19, 16, 
16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 
21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 25, 25, 25, 25, 24, 24, 24, 24, 23, 
23, 23, 23, 26, 26, 26, 26, 27, 27, 27, 27, 29, 29, 29, 29, 28, 
28, 28, 28, 30, 30, 30, 30, 37, 37, 37, 37, 38, 38, 38, 38, 31, 
31, 31, 31, 33, 33, 33, 33, 34, 34, 34, 34, 35, 35, 35, 35, 32, 
32, 32, 32, 36, 36, 36, 36, 39, 39, 39, 39, 40, 40, 40, 40, 41, 
41, 41, 41, 42, 42, 42, 42, 44, 44, 44, 44, 45, 45, 45, 45, 46, 
46, 46, 46, 47, 47, 47, 47, 48, 48, 48, 48, 49, 49, 49, 49, 51, 
51, 51, 51, 50, 50, 50, 50, 53, 53, 53, 53, 55, 55, 55, 55, 54, 
54, 54, 54, 56, 56, 56, 56), YEAR = c("2000", "2005", "2010", 
"2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", 
"2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", 
"2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", 
"2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", 
"2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", 
"2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", 
"2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", 
"2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", 
"2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", 
"2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", 
"2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", 
"2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", 
"2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", 
"2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", 
"2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", 
"2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", 
"2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", 
"2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", 
"2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", 
"2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", 
"2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", 
"2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", 
"2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", 
"2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", "2000", "2005", "2010", 
"2015"), GW_ratio = c(0.042477632204609, 0.0474244252684512, 
0.0468530944717599, 0.0563099372714334, 0.627107313487653, 0.646218602418209, 
0.67762854258841, 0.685904375700139, 0.507380103592701, 0.486206055781585, 
0.417048958873981, 0.459484594210496, 0.395890582250082, 0.3253835974443, 
0.392309560095165, 0.67370799310107, 0.181168320636236, 0.181749565222616, 
0.138339212060928, 0.144086431053441, 0.130357217001122, 0.183189346635182, 
0.251724495012261, 0.209386733470597, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.198471418535482, 
0.200903656980503, 0.521905916121804, 0.320771979285442, 0.616858488368295, 
0.616357077214462, 0.644082698433896, 0.630872473186906, 0.219519461834756, 
0.20835835946347, 0.26654012337858, 0.342464951512001, 0.20327767972392, 
0.205396942988966, 0.217485731517877, 0.23958267351698, 0.212746037100728, 
0.224170544036685, 0.246371223627517, 0.30070492044441, 0.0638086858467227, 
0.0828169240368195, 0.0702846885633481, 0.087115263327625, 0.0682199167413785, 
0.0791631599735217, 0.088197644840104, 0.10263868890634, 0.54472405467709, 
0.798135310118942, 0.813913475601118, 0.684709212339609, 0.0395170409214453, 
0.0345322220538875, 0.045046045115021, 0.0686811921479681, 0.169707872662818, 
0.152872423170933, 0.201408508516781, 0.220198901290643, 0.232551613785167, 
0.225503038300494, 0.295311130933392, 0.37342687547603, 0.1334906871804, 
0.152375302703019, 0.149676472797773, 0.207913484636338, 0.0971481333745429, 
0.217237841131022, 0.242425087723323, 0.221570943446764, 0.087696387736288, 
0.0907676851615112, 0.0798124601615004, 0.0983253948535604, 0.192004816090179, 
0.216934192352405, 0.195888655255663, 0.246199697595949, 0.219954845792504, 
0.199145945990002, 0.215674455989136, 0.20979560112079, 0.803659827642707, 
0.783688386032083, 0.708076577368411, 0.841720041773662, 0.0222962327241158, 
0.0276221040627481, 0.0345979685728171, 0.0189492408081628, 0.0571017281865951, 
0.0580066089067338, 0.0591458288540362, 0.0550429574909121, 0.116559876306407, 
0.113957245044631, 0.131833842307626, 0.144635043177616, 0.638787329763681, 
0.608273744093085, 0.580647907662318, 0.608759450195171, 0.194562698555409, 
0.21815853854413, 0.251561761241795, 0.332331878843668, 0.255270209393035, 
0.289895064795234, 0.294402602708839, 0.288580376805243, 0.467963517532187, 
0.500184752622255, 0.491063547973322, 0.476014332873024, 0.271919954988288, 
0.415057961794428, 0.458456209849688, 0.474846153757919, 0.117656974234047, 
0.0767995348654146, 0.121116850353801, 0.155855784524381, 0.0902771945485374, 
0.0956679322361892, 0.115000008037517, 0.148649643282071, 0.443561018588233, 
0.374081591755044, 0.361302531578788, 0.535183436045247, 0.13401113363223, 
0.296264909450639, 0.317050720406294, 0.22387792393992, 0.0555135846591771, 
0.0633769344439639, 0.0824388672286083, 0.102028531446501, 0.184019631231116, 
0.17593797261774, 0.241066018891551, 0.23101730662798, 0.0448746991845387, 
0.0469749515349067, 0.0500186827793563, 0.0590274510016283, 0.417894476848351, 
0.541120323176884, 0.544014489543699, 0.595276645112061, 0.0351856422067951, 
0.0446839905850666, 0.0600482642962501, 0.0658792059988603, 0.33863132342172, 
0.339167397006677, 0.292733260428039, 0.316323166757015, 0.213478689138264, 
0.184267061036214, 0.251762080987954, 0.275585752589778, 0.0521882485280308, 
0.04268339389438, 0.0621164525163083, 0.060139685625793, 0.0993926732335691, 
0.0832622306185065, 0.0988700914971501, 0.396256507852994, 0.277867335312144, 
0.249703136944933, 0.320435455534088, 0.356401769753973, 0.18608151348091, 
0.17791688167625, 0.221437820979801, 0.245457798001288, 0.00992077580664104, 
0.0286672420510461, 0.0326106850283666, 0.0522830292701699, 0.107377764076222, 
0.118147914123412, 0.116508525609751, 0.0789815526349038), SW_ratio = c(0.957522367795391, 
0.952575574731549, 0.95314690552824, 0.943690062728567, 0.372892686512347, 
0.353781397581791, 0.32237145741159, 0.314095624299861, 0.492619896407299, 
0.513793944218415, 0.58295104112602, 0.540515405789504, 0.604109417749918, 
0.6746164025557, 0.607690439904835, 0.32629200689893, 0.818831679363764, 
0.818250434777384, 0.861660787939072, 0.855913568946559, 0.869642782998878, 
0.816810653364818, 0.748275504987739, 0.790613266529403, 1, 1, 
0.5, 1, 0.801528581464519, 0.799096343019497, 0.478094083878196, 
0.679228020714558, 0.383141511631705, 0.383642922785538, 0.355917301566104, 
0.369127526813094, 0.780480538165244, 0.79164164053653, 0.73345987662142, 
0.657535048487999, 0.79672232027608, 0.794603057011034, 0.782514268482123, 
0.76041732648302, 0.787253962899272, 0.775829455963315, 0.753628776372483, 
0.69929507955559, 0.936191314153277, 0.91718307596318, 0.929715311436652, 
0.912884736672375, 0.931780083258621, 0.920836840026478, 0.911802355159896, 
0.89736131109366, 0.45527594532291, 0.201864689881058, 0.186086524398882, 
0.315290787660391, 0.960482959078555, 0.965467777946112, 0.954953954884979, 
0.931318807852032, 0.830292127337182, 0.847127576829066, 0.79859149148322, 
0.779801098709358, 0.767448386214833, 0.774496961699506, 0.704688869066608, 
0.62657312452397, 0.8665093128196, 0.847624697296981, 0.850323527202227, 
0.792086515363662, 0.902851866625457, 0.782762158868978, 0.757574912276677, 
0.778429056553236, 0.912303612263712, 0.909232314838489, 0.9201875398385, 
0.901674605146439, 0.807995183909821, 0.783065807647595, 0.804111344744337, 
0.753800302404051, 0.780045154207496, 0.800854054009998, 0.784325544010865, 
0.79020439887921, 0.196340172357293, 0.216311613967917, 0.291923422631589, 
0.158279958226339, 0.977703767275884, 0.972377895937252, 0.965402031427183, 
0.981050759191837, 0.942898271813405, 0.941993391093266, 0.940854171145964, 
0.944957042509088, 0.883440123693593, 0.886042754955369, 0.868166157692374, 
0.855364956822384, 0.361212670236319, 0.391726255906915, 0.419352092337682, 
0.391240549804829, 0.80543730144459, 0.78184146145587, 0.748438238758205, 
0.667668121156332, 0.744729790606965, 0.710104935204766, 0.705597397291161, 
0.711419623194757, 0.532036482467813, 0.499815247377745, 0.508936452026678, 
0.523985667126977, 0.728080045011712, 0.584942038205572, 0.541543790150312, 
0.525153846242081, 0.882343025765953, 0.923200465134585, 0.878883149646199, 
0.844144215475619, 0.909722805451463, 0.904332067763811, 0.884999991962483, 
0.851350356717929, 0.556438981411767, 0.625918408244956, 0.638697468421212, 
0.464816563954753, 0.86598886636777, 0.70373509054936, 0.682949279593706, 
0.77612207606008, 0.944486415340823, 0.936623065556036, 0.917561132771392, 
0.897971468553499, 0.815980368768884, 0.82406202738226, 0.75893398110845, 
0.76898269337202, 0.955125300815461, 0.953025048465093, 0.949981317220644, 
0.940972548998372, 0.582105523151649, 0.458879676823116, 0.4559855104563, 
0.404723354887939, 0.964814357793205, 0.955316009414934, 0.93995173570375, 
0.93412079400114, 0.66136867657828, 0.660832602993323, 0.707266739571961, 
0.683676833242985, 0.786521310861736, 0.815732938963786, 0.748237919012046, 
0.724414247410222, 0.947811751471969, 0.95731660610562, 0.937883547483692, 
0.939860314374207, 0.900607326766431, 0.916737769381494, 0.90112990850285, 
0.603743492147006, 0.722132664687856, 0.750296863055067, 0.679564544465911, 
0.643598230246028, 0.813918486519089, 0.82208311832375, 0.778562179020199, 
0.754542201998712, 0.990079224193359, 0.971332757948954, 0.967389314971633, 
0.94771697072983, 0.892622235923778, 0.881852085876588, 0.883491474390249, 
0.921018447365096)), row.names = c(NA, -196L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Now I want to make subsets for climate zones. For example for the high plains this means that I want to have a subset of the dataframe that only contains the following rows for `STATE`: ND, SD, WY, NE, KS, CO. I tried this for one state with the following code:

`HIGH_PLAINS= USGSratios[USGSratios$STATE == 'ND' ,]`

But how can I now do this for the multiple states that I've listed above? Seems a bit arbitrary to create the rows for all the states and then bind the rows together into one frame...

Comment: You can use: `%in%`

Comment: `HIGH_PLAINS= USGSratios[USGSratios$STATE %in% c('ND', 'SD', 'WY', 'NE', 'KS', 'CO') ,]`

Comment: Thanks a million, that did the job!